# Integral of two modified Bessel functions of order 0 and 1

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I'd like to calculate
$$
\int_0^R r^2 \left[ I_0(r)K_1(r) + I_1(r)K_0(r) \right] \mathrm{d}r
$$

Earlier, I have used the property $$\int x I_0(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = x I_1(x)$$ but I can't find a similar standard integral in books and tables for my problem. From another source I am hoping the answer to be like $\frac{R^2}{2}$, but Mathematica gives a complicated answer involving Meijer G-functions. Integrating by parts doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand can be rewritten. Firstly, using these relations for the derivatives:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}I_0}{dx}=I_1 $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}K_0}{dx}=-K_1 $$
I can write
$$ I_0 K_1 + K_0 I_1 = -I_0 K_0' + K_0 I_0' = - W(I_0, K_0)
$$
and then using the identity from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784386/wronskian-relation-of-modified-bessel-functions), $W(I_0, K_0) = - \frac{1}{x}$, the integral above becomes

$$ \int_0^R\! r\, \mathrm{d} r = \frac{R^2}{2} $$
as expected.